# AWS EC2 Performance explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-ec2

I have a REST API web server, built in .NetCore, that has data heavy APIs.

This is hosted on AWS EC2, I have noticed that the average response time for certain APIs are ~4 seconds and if I turn up the AWS-EC2 specs, the response time goes down to a few milliseconds. I guess this is expected, what I don't understand is that even when I load test the APIs on a lower end CPU, the server never crosses 50% utilization of memory/CPU. So what is the correct technical explanation that makes the APIs perform faster if the lower end CPU never reaches a 100% utilization of memory/CPU?

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple answer, there are so many ec2 variations you need to first figure out what is slowing down your API.

When you 'turn up' your ec2 instance, you are getting some combination of more memory, faster cpu, faster disk and more network bandwidth - and we can't tell which one of those 'more' features are improving your performance. Different instance classes ar optimized for different problems.

It could be as simple as the better network bandwidth, or it could be that your application is disk-bound and the better instance you chose is optimized for i/O performance.

Depending on what feature your instance is lacking, it would help you decide which type of instance to upgrade to - or as you have found out, just upgrade to something 'bigger' and be happy with the performance (at the tradeoff of being more expensive).